# How to open app when notification received without user interaction In React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to open app when notification received without user interaction

I am using react native push notification library for Push notification. App should auto start from background and quit state without user interaction and getInitialNotification method should be called. I want to invoke app on specific notification type.

```
===============================================

File: RNPushNotificationHelper

===============================================



public void invokeApp(Bundle bundle) {

    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();

    try {
        Class<?> activityClass = Class.forName(className);
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, activityClass);

        if(bundle != null) {
            activityIntent.putExtra("notification", bundle);
        }

        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(activityIntent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Class not found", e);
        return;
    }
}

===============================================

File: RNReceivedMessageHandler

===============================================


 // If notification ID is not provided by the user for push notification, generate one at random
 if (bundle.getString("id") == null) {
    SecureRandom randomNumberGenerator = new SecureRandom();
    bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(randomNumberGenerator.nextInt()));
}

Application applicationContext = (Application) context.getApplicationContext();

RNPushNotificationConfig config = new RNPushNotificationConfig(mFirebaseMessagingService.getApplication());  
RNPushNotificationHelper pushNotificationHelper = new RNPushNotificationHelper(applicationContext);

boolean isForeground = pushNotificationHelper.isApplicationInForeground();

RNPushNotificationJsDelivery jsDelivery = new RNPushNotificationJsDelivery(context);
bundle.putBoolean("foreground", isForeground);
bundle.putBoolean("userInteraction", false);
jsDelivery.notifyNotification(bundle);

// If contentAvailable is set to true, then send out a remote fetch event
if (bundle.getString("contentAvailable", "false").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
    jsDelivery.notifyRemoteFetch(bundle);
}

Log.v(LOG_TAG, "invokeApp: " + bundle);
pushNotificationHelper.invokeApp(bundle);

if (config.getNotificationForeground() || !isForeground) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "sendNotification: " + bundle);
    pushNotificationHelper.sendToNotificationCentre(bundle);
}
```

But It does not seem to work in Background OR Quit state. I checked logcat it showing logs when in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

#### Notification actions

I am assuming that this is not possible because it would be a major security gap.

In the Android docs, only the tap on the notification and notification actions are listed as options for actions in the background.
[The section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=de#Actions).

#### Restrictions bypasses

There is a so-called "Restrictions on starting activities from the background" from Android 10 (API level 29).

However, these have [several exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions).
I think the most interesting for you are these:

- The app receives a notification PendingIntent from the system. In the
  case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app
  can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is
  sent.
- The app has been granted the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the
  user.